# What dropdown control is used for Internet Explorer Bars in IE8?

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, combobox

Would anybody be able to identify this drop-down combo box located in the image below?[image: Drop Down Combo Box Control in Internet Explorer 8]

I am attempting to mimic the same look/feel, but am unable to find the control in the standard toolbox set and was hoping somebody can help identify it.

Comment: Couldn't you make one of these of your own with a `User Control`?

Comment: @Brian UserControl = WPF.  This control is derived from a winform control.

Comment: @Magnum, `UserControl` is a control in Winforms too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably after a `ToolStripSplitButton` with `DisplayStyle` set to `ImageAndText`.

[image]